# flask-sqlalchemy unit test issue

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Im trying to mock flask-sqlalchemy (3.0) query in the flask application. But query mock always return none

This is the test case

```
class TestVerify(TestCase):

    @patch("middleware.operations.models.user.User")
    def test_verify_token_request(self, user_query_mock: MagicMock) -> None:
        user_query_mock.query.return_value.filter_by.return_value.first.return_value = (
            User(user_id=4)
        )

        def verified_func(*args, **kwargs) -> bool:
            del args, kwargs
            return True

        with app.test_request_context(
            data=json.dumps({"user_id": 123}), content_type="application/json"
        ):

            response = verify_token_request(verified_func)
            result = response()  
            print(result)
```

This is the function im trying to mock

```
def verify_token_request(func: Callable) -> Callable:

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> str:

        user = User.query.filter_by(user_id=request.json["user_id"]).first()
        print(user)

        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

There user always none even if I assign user instance for query mock